# UITextView Attributed text with 2 links, each with different colors not working

Tags: swift, swift3, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to display in an attributed string 2 links, each link with a different color. I do not understand how to do that. It will always set just one color. I've been struggling with this for days and still can't figure out how to make it work. Does anybody know? I can set two colors but not for links! All links are the same color.

This is my whole implementation: (UPDATE)

```
  var checkIn = ""
  var friends = ""

//MARK: Change Name Color / Font / Add a second LABEL into the same label
    func setColorAndFontAttributesToNameAndCheckIn() {
        let nameSurname = "\(postAddSetup.nameSurname.text!)"
        checkIn = ""
        friends = ""

        if selectedFriends.count == 0 {
            print("we have no friends...")
            friends = ""
        } else if selectedFriends.count == 1 {
            print("we have only one friend...")
            friends = ""
            friends = " is with \(self.firstFriendToShow)"
        } else if selectedFriends.count > 1 {
            print("we have more than one friend...")
            friends = ""
            friends = " is with \(self.firstFriendToShow) and \(self.numberOfFriendsCount) more"
        }

        if checkIn == "" {
            checkIn = ""
        }

        var string = postAddSetup.nameSurname.text
        string = "\(nameSurname)\(friends)\(checkIn) "

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14), range: (string! as NSString).range(of: nameSurname))

        attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13), range: (string! as NSString).range(of: checkIn))
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13), range: (string! as NSString).range(of: friends))

        attributedString.addLink("checkIn", linkColor: UIColor.darkGray, text: checkIn)
        attributedString.addLink("tagFriends", linkColor: UIColor.red, text: friends)

        //attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "checkIn", range: (string! as NSString).range(of: checkIn))
        //attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "tagFriends", range: (string! as NSString).range(of: friends))

        //postAddSetup.nameSurname.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redIWorkOut(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)]

        //attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.darkGray, range: (string! as NSString).range(of: checkIn))

        postAddSetup.nameSurname.attributedText = attributedString


        print("atribute: \(attributedString)")

    }


func string1Action() {
    print("action for string 1...")
}

func string2Action() {
    print("action for string 2...")
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

    if URL.absoluteString == "string1" {
        string1Action()
    } else if URL.absoluteString == "string2" {
        string2Action()
    }
    return false
}

extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func addLink(_ link: String, linkColor: UIColor, text: String) {
        let pattern = "(\(text))"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern,
                                             options: NSRegularExpression.Options(rawValue: 0))
        let matchResults = regex.matches(in: self.string,
                                         options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                         range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.string.characters.count))

        for result in matchResults {
            self.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: link, range: result.rangeAt(0))
            self.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: linkColor, range: result.rangeAt(0))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used in a project this `NSMutableAttributedString extension` adapted from this [Article.](https://octodev.net/changing-uitextview-hyperlink-color/)

Using `NSRegularExpression` you can assign your respective color matching the range of your link text:

**The extension:**

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func addLink(_ link: String, linkColor: UIColor, text: String) {
        let pattern = "(\(text))"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern,
                                              options: NSRegularExpression.Options(rawValue: 0))
        let matchResults = regex.matches(in: self.string,
                                options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.string.characters.count))

        for result in matchResults {
            self.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: link, range: result.rangeAt(0))
            self.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: linkColor, range: result.rangeAt(0))
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Set a custom UITextView class to use this extension and using the delegate function shouldInteractWith url it’s possible to simulate the hyperlink logic of UITextView:

```
 class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    private let linksAttributes = [NSLinkAttributeName]

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let tapGest = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onTapAction))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGest)
    }

    @objc private func onTapAction(_ tapGest: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = tapGest.location(in: self)
        let charIndex = self.layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: self.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        if charIndex < self.textStorage.length {
            var range = NSMakeRange(0, 0)

            for linkAttribute in linksAttributes {
                if let link = self.attributedText.attribute(linkAttribute, at: charIndex, effectiveRange: &range) as? String {
                    guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
                    _ = self.delegate?.textView?(self, shouldInteractWith: url, in: range, interaction: .invokeDefaultAction)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

`attributedString.addLink(yourLinkUrl, linkColor: yourLinkColor, text: yourLinkText)`
`let textView = CustomTextView()
textView.attributedText = attributedString`

Comment: Hi Francesco. Great workaround for making the links. Unfortunately, it still keeps the same color on both links. It only takes the last color assigned.

Comment: Hi @MarianPetrisor with this you don’t have to use linkTextAttributes property, just set the attributed text.

Comment: I took out the linkTextAttributes the color and the links and left only this code. Now it's assigning automatically the default color. The links work, it's finding the right text but the color it's not assigned: `attributedString.addLink("string1", linkColor: UIColor.red, text: string1)`

Comment: @MarianPetrisor if you update your code with the current implementation, I will check it ;)

Comment: Thank you, Francesco! In this implementation, it works great! ;)